# angularJS create css friendly class name from data value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to convert a data value into a friendly css class name.

My category title is accessed as {{catTitle}} but I also want to apply a background image to the div containing the title.

I have a series of css classes to handle the images and these match the naming convention "category-title"

e.g. Video Games > class="video-games"

Can I process the data value to lowercase and replace spaces and symbols (like ' or /) with hyphens? Then apply that to the div using (I imagine) ng-class.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, i provided this solution.

I assume your result set will be,

```
  $scope.categoryDetails = [{
    "categoryId": "001",
    "categoryTitle": "Video Games",
    "categoryTypeId": "1"
  }, {
    "categoryId": "003",
    "categoryTitle": "Tester'Data",
    "categoryTypeId": "2"
  }, {
    "categoryId": "005",
    "categoryTitle": "Master/Slave",
    "categoryTypeId": "3"
  }];
```

I convert it to lowercase and replace the possible scenarios with `-` hyphen.

```
$scope.getCategoryTitleClassName = function(catTitle) {
    var returnTitle = '';
    returnTitle = catTitle.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-").replace("'", "-").replace("/", "-");
    return returnTitle;
};
```

**In the html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>File Name</th>
      <th>|</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="category in categoryDetails">
      <td><span ng-bind="category.categoryTitle"></span>
      </td>
      <td>|</td>
      <td ng-class=getCategoryTitleClassName(category.categoryTitle)>
        <span>{{getCategoryTitleClassName(category.categoryTitle)}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.video-games{
  background-color: red;
}

.tester-data {
   background-color: orange;
}

.master-slave {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GUqm9I6wXTvBsVU2nNun?p=preview

If my assumption is wrong, please share more information.

Comment: HI, that sorted it out straight away thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

```
<div ng-class="catTitle.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-')"></div>
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your help - unfortunately the .replace section didnt seem to work. In my rendered HTML it literally wrote out the string above. If I removed the .replace and just had lowercase that did actually parse to become a css class, but I couldnt seem to get the replace to work.

Comment: Actually, I inspected the DOM with Chrome and it is writing a class of ng-scope in the css section but not the parsed expected class of category-title. As I say, without the .replace portionof the command it does render  "category title" to lowercase so its 50% there :)